# what is this texture stretching caused from and how to fix it

Tags: modeling, texturing, uv-image-editor

As you can see in the picture. The plastic texture is stretching the closer it got to the corner, and the top is also stretching its own way and bending like a U shape. I pressed U and selected cube projection because it is a cube. There is a subsurface modifier being used in the first photo. In the second photo, I turned the modifier off.

[image]

[image]

Now I did apply the subsurface and re-select all the faces and do a cube projection again and that seems to solve it but is there a way to solve this issue without applying the modifier in case I wanted to change the shape and not have to deal with all the extra subdivided lines all over the faces?

Comment: It could be your subdivision modifier, you probably need to add some cuts there (CTRl + R)

Comment: I do have some cute there in the UV editor panel showing that I have one on either ends of the sides of the box and I also have them on the top edge of the box, but the only way I could fix the issue is if I applied the modifier and then didn't another cube projection. I was hoping to be able to resolve the issue without having to apply it, so I could manipulate it more if I wanted.